# Sources synchronization on many servers at the same time

Tags: data-synchronization

I'm writing my private learner websites on 3 servers. On each I'm trying to use the same class.php, functions.php and settings.php.
I want the changes in e.g. class.php I'm writing in one of the sites will be synchronized automatically in other servers.
I use Dreamweaver but I don't think the program will help. It helps to synchronize, but not on more then one server. Also please note, that other 2 servers are NOT test-servers but independent websites.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could properly use a version control or source code management system like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). Actually I am not pretty sure, if it can work automatically, but you should take a look.